# Code running even after response is sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on an API that returns **unix timestamp** and the **natural date** when a valid **natural date** in the form **January 5, 2016** or a **unix timestamp**  is passed in request. However, if I pass an **invalid date** the response should return **null** as `{ unix : null, natural : null`}. 
When I pass in a valid date, it does return the expected response. But it runs both block of codes i.e the valid block and the invalid block.The console.log("reach") from the `else` block is also run and logged in console. Should that statement run ? considering that the `if` block has already finished.

Here is the code

```
var moment = require('moment');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get(/\/$/,(req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

app.get('/:date',(req,res) => {
  var date,unix,natural;
  if(moment(req.params.date, "MMMM DD, YYYY").isValid() || moment(Number(req.params.date),"X").isValid())
    {
      if(moment(req.params.date,"MMMM D, YYYY",true).isValid()){
        date = moment(req.params.date,"MMMM D, YYYY");
        console.log('set from MM');
        unix = date.format("X");
        natural = date.format("MMMM DD, YYYY");
        res.json({
        unix: unix,
        natural: natural
      });
    }
      else if(moment(Number(req.params.date),"X").isValid()){
        date = moment(Number(req.params.date),"X");
        natural = date.format("MMMM DD, YYYY");
        unix = date.format("X");
        console.log('set from X');
        res.json({
        unix: unix,
        natural: natural
      });
    }
  }
  else{
    console.log("reach");
    res.send({
      unix: null,
      natural: null
    });
  }
});

var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

Link to live version

> https://unix-time-.glitch.me/

Comment: Try moving the last trailing `}` after the `else if` block after the last `if` block i.e `else { console.log("reach"); res.send({...); }); }}`. Seems like you have an extra closing bracket in your code?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying @Cyclonecode and also there are no extra closing `}`.

Comment: Try `console.log('reach', req.url)` to show which URL is responsible for the request.

Comment: Oh. It is /favicon.ico. Thanks.

Comment: @ZameerHaque welcome ;D

Comment: @robertklep How can I stop /favicon.ico from targeting /:date route ? Not possible ?

Comment: @ZameerHaque various solutions: add an actual `favicon.ico` to your public directory, add a specific route for `/favicon.ico` that returns a 404, check if `req.params.date` equals `favicon.ico`, make `:date` match a specific format instead of accepting any string.

Comment: @robertklep Match :date to specific format, how ? regex ?

Comment: @ZameerHaque yes, sort of. But since it should accept strings like _"January 5, 2016"_, that might be tricky. If it should _just_ accept timestamps, it'd be easier because you can match on an all-number parameter.

Comment: @robertklep thanks.